# Syntax for chartjs datalabels plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, chart.js

Could not find a simple example for this:
Trying to create a curved line in Chart.js and add fairly simple labels.
Got close but need some help as my JS is not my forte and the documentation is a bit confusing.
So, I have 1 line with 4 dots (x,y) and a second dataset with 1 dot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <canvas id="linechart" width="500" height="500" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 400px; width: 400px;"/>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"/>
        <script>
var linedata = {
    datasets: [
{
data: [{x:70,y:50}]},
        {
        datasets: [{
      // Change options only for labels of THIS DATASET
      datalabels: {
        color: 'yellow'
      }
    }],
            data: [{
                x: 0,
                y: 90
            }, {
                x: 69,
                y: 78
            }, {
                x: 150,
                y: 55
            }, {
                x: 165,
                y: 0
            }
],
            showLine: true,
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.4,
            bezierCurve: true,
            borderColor: 'rgba(10, 200, 40, 1)'
        }
    ]
};
var chartOptions = {
plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'blue',
        labels: {
          title: {
            font: {
              weight: 'bold'
            }
          },
          value: {
            color: 'green'
          }
        }
      }
},
 animation: {
        duration: 0
    },
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom',
  ticks: {
                stepSize: 10,
              max: 180
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 10,
              max: 100
            }
        }]
    }
};
var lineID = document.getElementById('linechart').getContext('2d');
var lineChart = new Chart(lineID, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: linedata,
    options: chartOptions,
    plugins:[ChartDataLabels]
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I need is the syntax to define each dot as 'predefined text'+value/
for example the second dot should say 'pressure: 65'.

I believe the answer is here:
https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#data-transformation
But my JS isn't good enough....

Answer (score 0):

surly this will help
try using formatter function in datalabels

https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#custom-labels

below return statement will give you the label defined for the point, alter ot as you like

```
datalabels: {
    formatter: function(value, context) {
      return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
    }
  }
```

this example below is the syntax you need

```
formatter: function(value, context) {
  return context.dataIndex + ': ' + Math.round(value*100) + '%';
 }

 // label for data at index 0 with value 0.23: "0: 23%"
 // label for data at index 1 with value 0.42: "1: 42%"
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Amihai. that is definitely the right direction! But I need to control the text of individual points. For the sake of simplicity - no data, just hard coded label. Can I add an array to pull from?

Comment: fotmatter will get you all the labels on each point, try write it down and console.log(value) inside the function youll see it